# Scala and IntelliJ: Don't break lines for simple bracketed lambdas

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I commonly write expressions such as:

```
result.map{_.map{_.toString}}.getOrElse(Nil).foldLeft("")(_ + _)
```

(which converts an Option[Seq[_]] into a single String by concatenation)

IntelliJ likes to reformat this so it looks like this:

```
result.map {
  _.map {
    _.toString
  }
}.getOrElse(Nil).foldLeft("")(_ + _)
```

I don't want it to do this.

I know putting expressions like this on one line is technically contrary to the style guide, but some things are just too simple to spread out.  It doesn't reformat if I use parentheses, but I have my reasons for not wanting to use parentheses sometimes.

Can I make IntelliJ cooperate?

Comment: Feel free to create feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL

Comment: `result.toSeq.flatten.mkString`

Comment: @jwvh but then I wouldn't have an example! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just use `()` instead of `{}`.

```
result.map(_.map(_.toString)).getOrElse(Nil).foldLeft("")(_ + _)
```

`()` syntax can only be used for lambdas with one expression, so all formatters will let it be a one liner (as long is it's not too long).

`{}` syntax is necessary if you have two or more expressions:

```
{ a =>
  val b = 1
  a + b
}
```

(we can kind of think of `{}` block as a whole as a single expression from the POV of what's outside of it, so *some* formatters might not add more new lines if we have e.g. `(a => b => { multiple lines })`).

Personally, I would also consider using scalafmt instead and configuring it to not add newlines if a whole expression fits into one line.

Comment: Looks like scalafmt is going to be the way to go here, thanks.